# How to insert a created <input> tag into a created <p> tag with text?

Tags: javascript, html, createelement

I'm trying to put a created `input` tag between the text of a created `p` tag. My method returns [object HTMLInputElement]. I want to create a text field for users to write in.

I've tried

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<script>
let PTag = document.createElement("p");

let Input = document.createElement("input");

Input.type = "text";

PTag.innerText = "SampleTextOne " + Input + " SampleTextTwo";

document.body.appendChild(PTag);
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I'm still new to creating HTML elements and positioning them.

Comment: What is the reason to add script ? Why are you not creating input tag in html ?

Comment: @SrushtiShah I would just use the HTML for it if I wasn't creating an unknown number of input tags maybe I could create it then copy it for the unknown number of times? (I plan on putting this in a for loop).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```html
<body>
<script>
let PTag = document.createElement("p");
let Input = document.createElement("input");

Input.type = "text";

PTag.innerHTML = "SampleTextOne ";
PTag.append(Input);
PTag.innerHTML += " SampleTextOne";

document.body.appendChild(PTag);
</script>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You inserting Html Object as text inside your p tag.

instead of innerText appendChild a created Html element inside a created tag to work correctly.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<script>
let PTag = document.createElement("p");

let Input = document.createElement("input");

Input.type = "text";

// PTag.innerText = "SampleTextOne " + Input + " SampleTextTwo";

PTag.appendChild(Input);

document.body.appendChild(PTag);
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

But it's better to create html elements without javascript like this

```
<input type="text" placeholder="enter text" />
```